Microphone only records white noise
After upgrading my linux kernel I have noticed the microphone records only noise, of course I have checked my microphone is working in windows but not in my current CentOS Stream 9.
Here are my system information:
$ uname -a
Linux localme 5.14.0-503.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Aug 22 17:03:23 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -vv | grep -i audio
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
07:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller

$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [LG HDR WFHD]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC897 Analog [ALC897 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   208896  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   114688  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_scodec_component    20480  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
snd_hda_intel          61440  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       40960  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         225280  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          155648  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq               131072  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               192512  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              53248  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   159744  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd

$ inxi -Aaz
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    vendor: Sapphire driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s
    lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:aaf0 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 07:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k5.14.0-503.el9.x86_64 status: kernel-api
    tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.1 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin tools: pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl

$  lspci -kvd::403
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Device aaf0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 72, IOMMU group 16
    Memory at fce60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

07:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    DeviceName: Realtek ALC1220
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a194
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 74, IOMMU group 21
    Memory at fcb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

